# transactiontoolargeexception while sending image via email through intent extra

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

this is my code where I want to attach image to email and send it.

```
    String receiverEmail = receiver.getText().toString().trim();
    String to[] = {receiverEmail};
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.setType("imge/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello wats up");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap );
    startActivity(intent);
```

I am getting error which says

```
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1331968 bytes
```

This issue is with the bitmap file. How to reduce the size.?
Help me with the issue. Thank you in advance.

```
{
oncreate method....
I have my bitmap here created with instance name bitmap which i want to send in email attachment
Uri bitmapUri = getImageUri(OutgoingEmbededImage.this, bitmap); //null pointer exception error here
String bitmapPath = getPathOfUri(bitmapUri);
end of on create method
}

//getting bitmapUri here 
 private Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap myBitmap){
 ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
 String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), myBitmap, "Image", null);
 return Uri.parse(path);
}

//string path here
public String getPathOfUri(Uri uri){
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(index);
}
```

Getting error on mentioned line with comments.
If I get bitmap path then i can pass that in below line I guess... correct me if I am wrong. And hope you will understand the issue I mentioned in my code so you can help me.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA, bitmapPath);
```

Comment: Aalap, instead of editing my answer edit your post with latest code and issue which u are getting

Comment: I updated my post here and the error is on the line mentioned. Please help me resolving it..

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap );
```

line causing issue because `bitmap` size is very large as *allowed Binder transaction buffer size.*

See here:

[TransactionTooLargeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) :

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb,
>   which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.
>   Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many
>   transactions in progress even when most of the individual transactions
>   are of moderate size.

So, to fix this issue instead of passing Bitmap of image using `Intent.putExtra`, use *image url,file path,URI,Drawable id,...* to send minimum size data.